# Angular universal treating favicon.ico as a route in server side

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-universal

I am working on a Angular universal project that is deployed on Elastic beanstalk.There is a route `{ path: ':id', component: DynamiccomponentComponent, canActivate: [ DynamicRouteGuard ] }` so that it can produce dynamic route and generate content dynamically for that route if available in DB. But in route guard i can see from server side log **favicon.ico** is appearing there.I need to prevent **favicon.ico** from appearing on route guard. Any Idea?

Comment: Modify `server.ts` to create a route to serve this file

Comment: @David Shoud i modify this? - `// All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });`

Comment: Actually, normally you should have a `server.get('*.*',express.static(...` route which should serve `favicon.ico` file. If it does not and you cannot understand why, add a `server.get('/favicon.ico`,...) route (before the `server.get('*',...` to make sure that file is handled as a static file